Performance tuning of Update statement in ORACLE
I have this code, and it is taking 8 to 9 hours for 450k rows of data to complete. How to improve performance in that case? tab_a has 10M of data.
Declare

cursor cur_dup is
Select col_a,col_b,count(1) from tab_a group by col_a,col_b having count(1) > 1;
Begin
  for cur_dup_rec in cur_dup loop
     
    update tab_a
    set qty = 0
    where col_a = cur_dup_rec.col_a and col_b = cur_dup_rec.col_b
    and trunc(u_created_date) <> (Select max(trunc(u_created_date)) from tab_a 
                                   where col_a = cur_dup_rec.col_a and col_b = cur_dup_rec.col_b);
                                   
    update tab_a
       set (u_modified_date) = trunc(sysdate)
     where col_a = cur_dup_rec.col_a and col_b = cur_dup_rec.col_b;
     
     for cur_dup2_rec in (Select distinct item,customer,location,requested_date 
                            from tab_a 
                           where col_a = cur_dup_rec.col_a and col_b = cur_dup_rec.col_b) loop
                           
           update tab_a
            set (u_modified_date) = trunc(sysdate)
            where item = cur_dup2_rec.item and customer = cur_dup2_rec.customer and location = cur_dup2_rec.location
            and to_char(requested_date,'DD-MON-YYYY') = cur_dup2_rec.requested_date;
            
     end loop;
  
  end loop;
End;


First step: How can I see the SQL execution plan in Oracle?, which can be used on every subquery to check if proper indexes are used.

A Decribe and How do I get information about an index ... in Oracle?, with the table info would be nice to see which indexes already do exist.

Indexed are fine in the TAB_A. item,customer,location,requested_date combination of these are the primary key. Is there any way to not using loop or using bulk collect in that case? Will Bulk Collect solve the problem ?

Can you make a (functional) description of what this code should do ?

Did you check How to find the cost of a stored procedure in Oracle and optimize it? and did help help (or why did that no help)   (Please use [edit] to provide these details, do not provide them in a comment)

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for a minimal set of sample data that is representative of your problem; an English (not code) explanation of the logic that you are trying to implement; and the expected output for your sample data.

"item,customer,location,requested_date combination of these are the primary key" Why are you using Select distinct item,customer,location,requested_date from tab_a? If they are the primary key then there will only ever be a single row with each combination so DISTINCT is pointless.

Most likely it's an indexing issue. You are invalidating any index use on requested_date, u_created_date by applying functions to those columns. However, if col_a,col_b is highly selective then the date filters may not be important. You definitely need to verify that you have a single multi-column index defined as (col_a,col_b) for all but the last update. For that one you will need to create another index with the columns of your predicate.

Secondly, it matters what % of the table you are modifying. If you are modifying a significant portion of the table, then you shouldn't update the table at all. You should rebuild it create table as select.... updates are very expensive at high volumes even if your execution plan is perfect. If you are somewhere in-between, you might explore removing the loop logic so you have a single update and enable parallel dml to leverage PX. But first ensure the correct plan and index use before proceeding further with anything else.

Stop using loops and use a single SQL statement.
For the first two UPDATEs you can use something like (untested because we do not have the CREATE TABLE or INSERT statements for your sample data):
MERGE INTO tab_a dst
USING (
  SELECT COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY col_a, colb) AS cnt,
         MAX(u_created_date) OVER (PARTITION BY col_a, colb) AS max_u_created_date
  FROM   tab_a
) src
ON (dst.ROWID = src.ROWID AND src.cnt > 1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET u_modified_date = TRUNC(SYSDATE),
      qty             = CASE
                        WHEN TRUNC(dst.u_modified_date) = TRUNC(src.max_u_created_date)
                        THEN dst.qty
                        ELSE 0
                        END;

I'm unsure what you are trying to achieve with the final UPDATE in the nested loop but you almost certainly don't want to use nested loops and want to convert it to an SQL statement.

Thanks @MTO. For second loop I made this one. MERGE INTO tab_a tgt
using
(Select distinct tab_a.item,tab_a.customer,tab_a.location,tab_a.requested_date from tab_a tab_a, (Select col_a,col_b from tab_a group by col_a,col_b having count(1) > 1) tab_b
where tab_a.col_a=tab_b.col_a
and tab_a.col_b=tab_b.col_b) src
on (tgt.item=src.item and tgt.customer=src.customer and tgt.location=src.location and tgt.requested_date=src.requested_date)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET u_modified_date = TRUNC(SYSDATE).
